Is it possible to put a crescendo on top of the staff markings?
I'm writing some music and the notes on a particular staff are divided. I only want one part to crescendo. How would I show that? Should I put the notation and stuff above the staff for the top part?

Dynamics for the upper part should be placed above the staff.
From Behind Bars, by Elaine Gould:

When parts sharing a stave have individual dynamics, each part must take separate stems. Dynamics for the up-stemmed part are then placed above the stave. (p. 101)


Is there any normal means of distinguishing situations where all dynamics are below the staff because all parts should share the same dynamics, from those where the upper part should be played at uniform volume and dynamic markings should only affect the lower part?

@supercat You could write senza cresc. above the upper part.
